# Ruby program do not launch

Tags: ruby

I'm new to ruby and I'am building a little program on ruby alone,the problem is that I'am trying to launch it without success

Imagine that i have this code

```
#usr/bin/ruby

Class Whatever

   def get_user_input
     @user_input = gets.chomp
     user_doing(@user_input)
   end

   def user_doing
    #something
   end

end
```

What I want is to call the get_user_input method as soon as i feed my rb file to ruby

I tried to call it on a initialize method

```
   def initialize
    get_user_input
   end
```

I also tried to define it as a "class method"

```
   def get_user_input
     @user_input = gets.chomp
     user_doing(@user_input)
   end
```

but neither of them seems to work as when I'm start the rb file the program doesn't expect my input so how can i do this?.

Comment: Where have you instantiated the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just define a class. What you did not call the method. Just add `Whatever.new.get_user_input` to your file.

```
#usr/bin/ruby

class Whatever

  def initialize(input)
    @input = input
  end

  def self.get_user_input
    whatever = new(gets.chomp)
    whatever.user_doing
  end

  def user_doing
    puts "Input was: #{@input}"
  end

end

Whatever.get_user_input
```

Btw: Your `user_doing` does not take args in the moment. You may want to check that.

Comment: thanks spicker for the answer, and thanks sawa to point those grammar errors feel free to correct me any time.

I did what you propose spickerbut and it worked, but now i have another question, unlike your example if i try to call user_doing on self.get_user_input it will give me an undefined_method error unless i define user_doing as self.user_doing why?

Comment: `def self.foo` defines a class method, whereas `def foo` defines a instance method. In my example `self.get_user_input` is a class method, it can be called without initialization of an instance. But `user_doing` is an instance method, therefore I call new in my example. If you want to follow object-oriented programming you should avoid having too many class methods.